# Ignoring last lines in CSV using Filehelpers if they aren't input

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I built a program using FileHelpers to parse CSV files and it works wonders, except I'm running into an issue.
Some of the files - but not all - have a number of extra lines in the end with information that does not pertain to actual fields.

like so

```
...
31,4104019, ,,1043,,,0,,Ventas Total Credito,1,1,277.98,0,0,0,0,21.5040000000,V,
31, ,11212302,,1043,,,0,,Ventas Total Credito,1,1,33.28,0,0,0,0,21.5040000000,V,
31, ,11212307,,1043,,,0,,Ventas Total Credito,1,1,277.98,0,0,0,0,21.5040000000,V,

;Importado="01/11/2013"
 //blank line here too
```

I know FileHelpers has the

```
[IgnoreLast(3)] 
public class whatever...
```

option, but as only some of the files have those extra 3 lines, Using this for all could result in the last 3 records being ignored for some files.

Is there any way to tell it when to ignore a line? Or should I read the file separately first and remove those lines myself?

Comment: Have you checked `FileHelperAsyncEngine.ReadNext` method and `BeforeReadRecord` event to set `e.SkipThisRecord = true;`

Comment: I like the beforereadrecord idea, I'll look into it. If you have any examples of how to use it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Am sorry, I just got this in their documentation. They have samples. Take a look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **BeforeReadRecord** event or implement in the record **INotifyRead** interface that is more simple.

In both cases use e.SkipThisRecord = true; in the cases that you need to discard

Comment: I'm sorry but I looked into the documentation and help file and there are no example of how to use BeforeReadRecord, if you can provide a simple example that would be helpful.

Comment: What is e? I tried both the engine and the result but neither has this property