# How to remove trailing empty lines in FileHelper

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Thought it would be easy, but cannot find any methods in FileHelpEngine to remove trailing empty lines in a text or csv file, which causes ReadFile to fail.

Comment: According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038031/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-trim-a-newline-off-of-a-string), `sb.ToString().TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' );` or `sb.ToString().TrimEnd( Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());` should work.

Comment: hope this link may be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933439/ignoring-last-lines-in-csv-using-filehelpers-if-they-arent-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of empty lines is known, for example 2, you can use in your record class:

```
[IgnoreLast(2)]
public class ...
```

Another option is to ignore empty lines but are ignored in any place they appear

```
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class ...
```

The last thing you can try is to ignore some lines by code using INotifyRead interface like:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowVariableLength)]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class OrdersFixed
    :INotifyRead
{
   [FieldFixedLength(7)]
   public int OrderID;

   [FieldFixedLength(8)]
   public string CustomerID;

   [FieldFixedLength(8)]
   public DateTime OrderDate;

   [FieldFixedLength(11)]
   public decimal Freight;


  public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.RecordLine.StartsWith(" ") ||
       e.RecordLine.StartsWith("-"))
        e.SkipThisRecord = true;
  }

  public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
  {   
    //  we want to drop all records with no freight
    if (Freight == 0)
        e.SkipThisRecord = true;

  }

}
```